# Validating UK Post Codes using regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, asp.net, regex

I want to validate a field with a UK Post Code. What regular expression could be used to validate this field?. `(([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Z]{0,1})\ ([0-9][A-Z]{2}))|(GIR\ 0AA)$` does appear valid because it has the exception **GIR 0AA**.

So, please help me to write an expression without any exception

Comment: This suddenly makes more sense if it does. PINs with letters in them seem a little unlikely (at least if they don't have any further information).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to try to validate post codes without an exception though … since the post code system has an exception to the normal rules in it.

Comment: @David, it doesn't make much sense to try and validate a post code using regular expressions, given there's so many caveats. It *could* be used to do a first-pass before consulting the [PAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcode_Address_File) though.

Answer (score 3):

If you do mean post code, [wikipedia has a section on validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation). One regex that it recommends is:

```
((A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRST]?|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]?|F[KY]|G[LUY]?|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]?|M[EKL]?|N[EGNPRW]?|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKLMNOPRSTY]?|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)[1-9]?[0-9]|([E|N|NW|SE|SW|W]1|EC[1-4]|WC[12])[A-HJKMNPR-Y]|[SW|W]([1-9][0-9]|[2-9])|EC[1-9][0-9]) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}
```

The advantage of this one is that it catches some invalid areas and districts.

Answer (score 1):

> **Side note:** `GIR 0AA` is listed as an exception in your regular
>   expression because it is a valid UK
>   [post code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom) for what are esentially
>   historical reasons (search for it in
>   the Wikipedia article, it's given
>   special mention).

There is no trivial regular expression you can write to validate a UK post code as there's no surety that, for example, GU78 2AB is valid (the GU78 outward area may only contain 2A*A*, but not 2A*B*), whereas GU77 2AB may well be considered valid.

You can use a regular expression to validate the **form and structure** of a piece of text to determine if it matches the requirements to be considered a post code. I believe that, broadly speaking, the following regular expression will satisfy that:

```
(([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})\ ([0-9][A-Z]{2}))|(GIR\ 0AA)$
```

Comment: Thanks for the response this really helped me a lot, I thought that was an exception now i understand it means

Answer (score 0):

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
```